# What happens in the LMO org when customer installs our app from appExchange?

Tags: appexchange

Could you please describe, what changes happens in the LMO when any new customer install an app from appexchange? Eg. Any new record of a perticular object is created in LMA or any lead is generated, etc. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an installer installs a managed package, a lead & License records are automatically created in the LMO. 
The lead contains the installer's name, company, and email address. The lead source defaults to 'Package Installation. 
License record contains additional information like the Installer's org ID, Installed package version, License status, Install date, Org Status, Instance, Org Edition